# updateMany and elemMatch in with nested schemas in mongoose (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query a MongoDB database via mongoose to updateMany the fields of my database. I suppose that the first request is correct because mongoose doesn't fire any error, but for the nested schemas, I'm getting the following error.

My goal is to delete the occurences of the userTag in friends and remove the friendRequestsSent when userTarget equals userTag, friendRequestsReceived when userRequest equals userTag and notification when data equals userTag.

**Here are the schemas of my Model**

```
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  type: Number,
  icon: String,
  data: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})

const FriendRequestSchema = new Schema({
  userRequest: { type: String, required: true },
  userTarget: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({   
  tag: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  friendRequestsSent: { type: [FriendRequestSchema] },
  friendRequestsReceived: { type: [FriendRequestSchema] },
  friends: { type: [String] },
  notifications: { type: [NotificationSchema] },
})
```

**The request**

```
const updateResponse = await User.updateMany(
        {
          friends: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userTag } },
          friendRequestsSent: {
            userTarget: {
              $elemMatch: { $eq: userTag },
            },
          },
          friendRequestsReceived: {
            userRequest: {
              $elemMatch: { $eq: userTag },
            },
          },
          notifications: {
            data: {
              $elemMatch: { $eq: userTag },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $pull: {
            friends: userTag,
            friendRequestsSent: { userTarget: userTag },
            friendRequestsReceived: { userRequest: userTag },
            notifications: { data: userTag },
          },
        }
      )
```

**The error**

```
Error while deleting the user account: Cast to String failed for value "{ '$elemMatch': { '$eq': '0eQzaAwpt' } }" at path "userRequest" for model "User"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `userRequest` field in `friendRequestsReceived` is type `String`, not array so `$elemMatch` will not work. Also, you don't need to use `$elemMatch` because you specify only a single  condition in the `$elemMatch` expression as it says in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query):

> If you specify only a single  condition in the $elemMatch expression, you do not need to use $elemMatch.

In your case, you just need to do something like (details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)):

```
await User.updateMany({
  friends: userTag,
  "friendRequestsSent.userTarget" : userTag,
  "friendRequestsReceived.userRequest": userTag,
  "notifications.data": userTag
}...
```